# How to work with the Raphael Canvas outside of the Raphael function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, raphael

Basically I have a list of projects, and within each project is a number of text elements.  Each text element is text wrapped based on the parameters of the canvas it's working on, and since I can have many many canvas elements, it slows things down with the wrapping.

I wanted to create the Raphael Canvas and text elements for all of my projects before the first one is open, and then easily switch between each set of text by hiding or showing, as I go through each project.

I found something here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/XVdHUbsgPXE

It wasn't very straightforward, and I couldn't get it working, so I'm curious if anyone has any other ideas?

Basically it goes

1. Get list of projects
2. do a few setup things based on that list.
3. Create first project as default.
4. Change projects.

I would like to create the Raphael canvas and the text within #2, and then reuse my Raphael canvas within #3 and 4.

Thanks all

EDIT:

So basically my code looks like this.

I have a Variable that is global outside my methods, lets say var a;

This is how my methods are setup

```
  var a;


    function alpha()
    {
            Raphael(function()
            {
                   a = Raphael(0,0,100,100);
                   a.text(2,5, "test");
                   document.body.appendChild(a.canvas);
            }
    }

function beta()
{
Raphael(function()
            {
           var rect = a.rect(0,0,100,100)
```

....
....

.......
                }
    }

When I try to call a from my second method it just says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rect' of undefined

This happened in another method as well.  I have different shapes that I hide and show, and was trying to call one by it's method and use Raphael's hide/show, but it wouldn't work.  I was able to get Jquery's to work for me though.

For some reason elements get messed up at some point.  Should I encapsulate my entire js in a Raphael I wonder... LEt me try :)

Comment: Try and post up a minimal jsfiddle highlighting the problem.

Comment: Will do, passed out last night so I will set one up this morning :).

Comment: Sorry it's been a few days, I tried to set up a Jsfiddle but I was having issues with it.

I updated my main post with the information on how my functions are setup.

Comment: You can't really tell on that which order the funcs are called in, or why you are using Raphs callbacks like that. I'd still put it on a fiddle

Comment: Sorry... Basically function 1 is called to create my text since that takes a long time to do, so I wanted to get that done first for everything.

  Then I want to call my second method, which creates everything else for the current scene.  Then I want to show or hide the text(text we did in the first function) based on a parameter to hide or show the text.

the canvas is undefined in function 2.

I'm not too sure about the "Raphael Callbacks" I'm assuming that's the "Raphael Function?"  I thought we had to use that in order to use Raphael commands, but maybe I'm confused/missing something :(.

Comment: I actually found a work around that is better for my needs, so thank you for  your time.  I am going to try to attempt a fiddle with this hopefully at a later date, but I have other things that are more urgent at the moment.  Thanks.